# Java generics - using a variable of type Class<? extends Whatever> (clazz cannot be resolved to a type)

Tags: java, class, generics

I keep struggling with Java generics, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
...
sortedActions = new ArrayList<BaseAction>();
ActionGroup<? extends BaseAction> actionGroup = null;

for (final BaseAction action : sortedActions) {
    Class<? extends BaseAction> clazz = action.getClass();
    if (actionGroup == null) {
        actionGroup = new ActionGroup<clazz>(); // <-- "clazz cannot be resolved to a type"
    }
}
```

And ActionGroup is defined like that:
    public class ActionGroup { ...

I don't understand this error, when I check in the debugger, clazz gets initialized, it is of type "java.lang.Class", its value is "my.packacge.SubAction" which is a subclass of BaseAction, so how is it not resolved to a type? Or, what am I not understanding here?

Comment: What goes between the angle brackets is not an instance of any variable, but the actual type name, e.g. `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `ArrayList<anInteger>`.

Comment: if it's not resolved, it doesn't compile. How did you debug?

Comment: Well I commented the problematic line to see what was clazz when getting there ^^

Comment: A variable is *not* a type. It doesn't matter that it has the type `Class<..>`. Only a type (including types introduced by generics) may appear as a generic type argument.

Comment: @rgettman okay I understand, so do you know what would be the good way to instanciate a new ActionGroup of the same generic type as clazz then?

Comment: @Gaetch Compiler warnings aside, simply `new ActionGroup()`. (That is, omit the generic type argument entirely.)

Comment: Then how to be sure afterwards that no wrong types will be added to the group? (ActionGroup is like a collection of the same type of actions).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that: the part between the angular brackets needs to be a type name known to the compiler, not a `Class<C>` object, which becomes known to your program only at run-time.

This is not allowed because generics in Java are almost purely a compile-time concept <sup>*</sup>. Generic type parameters are supplied to the compiler so that it could do additional type checking. If no compile-time checking is needed, you can use non-generic versions of the class without any additional costs or benefits.

---

<sup>*</sup> The compiler leaves traces of generics in the compiled code, e.g. in the class metadata, but that is pretty much the extent of it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create an `ActionGroup< T >` where `T` is not known at compile time.  @rgettman's comment hints at the fact that your syntax is incorrect for the `new ActionGroup` as you're trying to put a variable called `clazz` instead of the name of a class inside the `<>`; but you don't know which class until runtime.

You're better off adding a factory method that creates ActionGroups to your M1ssAction class and calling that method instead.

Comment: Mmmh oh yes okay I understand, the type is resolved at runtime indeed. But! As I'm trying to figure it out, I don't see how to deal with it with a factory method, if I have a BaseAction instance, it's type would be known only at runtime so how to make a method in BaseAction that could instanciate the generic type?

Comment: Well I mean I could override the method in each of the concrete class implementing BaseGroup but that's kind of disappointing that I have to do myActionInstance.createGroup(); but right now I don't see any other way?

Comment: I was insinuating that the BaseAction would be the place to put your createGroup() factory method, rather than BaseGroup.  It's lame, but less lame than the hideous reflection-based alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to understand here is that in Java, generic specializations are a compile time construct, and not a run time construct.  During the compilation process, the specializations are "erased" - this is called "type erasure" - and the generated byte code does not know what the specialization is.  You can't determine a class at runtime - which is what the getClass() function does - and use it at compile time.

The "extends" keyword is generally more useful for defining generics than for instantiating them.  In this case, what you probably want is for actionGroup to be ActionGroup, and assign to it new `ActionGroup<BaseAction>()` - or in Java 7, just new ActionGroup<>() - since you are instantiating an instance rather than defining the generic.  You can still stick objects that are a subclass of BaseAction in there, since they still "are" instances of BaseAction.  You can then drop the action.getClass() call.

Comment: Yes but then once instanciated I have no control over the Actions I can put inside ActionGroup (all should be of the same type than the first instance I put inside in the first place). I know about type erasure, but it's hard to really see it lurking behind your code until some compilation error pops up. Sooo, now I figured out how to instanciate ActionGroup, now I'm trying to find how to compare later Actions with the Action generic parameter of my ActionGroup ^^

Comment: Got it, since now I use an instance of AnAction to create a new ActionGroup<AnAction>, I forced the instance to be a parameter of the ActionGroup constructor (so it can become its first member at the same time). So when I want to test if a BaseAction can go into my ActionGroup I have a function in ActionGroup:
`public boolean canContain(final M1ssAction action) { return this.actionList.get(0).equals(action.getClass());}`